# How to apply filter in json file using angular 2

Tags: json, angular2-template, angularjs-filter

I am trying to filter the json content as per the user input with the help of pipe in Angular 2, but it is not filtering at all and showing no output, I may be missing something please suggest. Given below my code snippets.

```html
<div>
    <label>name:
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="test" placeholder="enter here">
    </label>
</div>

<ul *ngFor="let post of posts | filterBy: test">
          <li >{{post.Name}}</li>
          <li >{{post.City}}</li>
     <li >{{post.Country}}
</li>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Insted of

```
<ul *ngFor="let post of posts | filterBy: test">
```

try

```
<ul *ngFor="let post of posts | filter: test">
```

Comment: Not helping..showing error : unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'filter' could not be found